# PhoneGap 2.7.0 returns iPad user-agent string on iPhone

Tags: ios, cordova

I've recently updated my PhoneGap iOS application to version 2.7.0 - the update was mostly painless but my application now returns the user-agent string of an iPad even when installed on an iPhone. The weird part is that the `device` object correctly identifies the device as an iPhone but the user-agent string is wrong.

I realise I can just fudge my way around this issue by checking the `device.platform` property but I'd rather have a valid user-agent string since I send the string to Device Atlas.

Any idea why this is happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this what is the result ?

```
navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone");
```

If the result is < 0, it means that you aren't running on the IPhone

Comment: Thanks @gaepi, this would definitely work but if possible I'd like to retrieve the real user-agent string for use with Device Atlas (https://deviceatlas.com/).